# How Do I Keep A Progressive Web App Open In Background (Service Worker?)

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am currently making a PWA and the app has to be able to stay open in the background and keep doing a JavaScript loop. I couldn't find any good videos or articles on how to do this so I thought I might ask here. I heard I might need to do it via service worker? I am not too sure tbh.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What will the script be doing in this loop?

Comment: It's supposed to check to see if someones inside 5km radius of their set location
Basically All the Code Below Has To Run in the background:
https://hastebin.com/ehexuderis.js

Comment: You probably need to build a native app for that. The browser will at some point move into the background. You cannot stop it from doing that. When it the background it will no longer have GPS info.

Comment: you can't just run a PWA 24/7. Nor can you run an app for that matter. It drains the battery, and then there are privacy issues, etc.
Sounds like you are doing geo-fencing. Try to set those up through the Google and Apple wallets. You can do that with a PWA.

Comment: @ChrisLove Google and apple wallets how does that relate or connect into geofencing? And your still agreeing and saying i cannot run a pwa in the background right?

Comment: right you can't run an application 24/7. Even native apps are tombstoned. The wallet solution is executed outside of the application context. Still require the user to opt in, etc. But triggers notifications when they enter the fence.